# How to display label in UITableView

Tags: uitableview, ios5, storyboard

I created a `UIViewController` using story board in Xcode 4.2. Then added a `UITableView` object to it by dragging it on to the view controller. Then dragged a label to one of the cells of this `UITableView` and made label's text to be MyFirstLabel. Now when I run this in simulator I am not able to see the label. What am I missing ?

Answer (score 1):

You must create properties for UILabel when adding to cell
let's say you have a UILabel declaration like this(and connected to the object you drag on storyboard)

`@property(retain, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel* yourLabel;`
in your .h file and

```
@synthesize yourLabel;
```

in your .m file. After initializing the cell(on the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` delegate method)
add your label to the cell like this `[cell.contenView addSubview:yourLabel];` I hope this helps-if not, please give some more details about your problem

Comment: I did as you suggested but I am not sure if i am assigning the delegate and datasource to the table view correctly. I just press control and connected the data souce and delegate both to the view controller in which i am dragging the tableView in

Answer (score 0):

You *should* see the label. Make sure you have **static cells** for your table view. You do this by selecting the table view and change this in the inspector. Now you can create the exact number of sections and rows, including the content, right in storyboard.

If, however, you want to change the content of the label, you have to create an `IBOutlet`, still using static cells.

If you want to vary the number of sections and rows you will have to go with dynamic cells. In this case you should see the label if you have the correct **Cell Identifier** set in storyboard and referenced in your table view datasource method `cellForRowAtIndexPath`.

**EDIT**:
As has been pointed out, you cannot use static table views if not embedded in a table view controller (which claims the whole screen). So here is the workaround:

Option 1: you make it into dynamic cells as mentioned above and implement the datasource protocols in your ordinary view controller. You could then insert the label in code.

Option 2: as option 1, but with subclassing `UITableViewCell` where you can design the cell with a xib and create the necessary outlets.

Comment: if I use static cells then Xcode complaints : Static table view only valid when embedded in UITableViewController instances. I am not using Table view controller because i don't want the table to be on the entire page

Comment: Wow, I did not know that although it seems logical now. See my edit.